# How to open an arbitrary URL in new window using a PrimeFaces button

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have the below output link which does its job:

```
<h:outputLink value="#{verDocumentoController.url()}" target="_blank">
    show document
</h:outputLink>
```

It opens an URL obtained as a bean property in a new window.

However, I'd like to turn the link into a button in PrimeFaces look'n'feel. I tried as below:

```
<p:commandButton value="show document" action="#{verDocumentoController.url()}" 
    onclick="form.target='_blank'" ajax="false" />
```

But it only reopens the current page in a new window and not the URL specified as bean property. How can I achieve this anyway?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `<p:commandButton>` basically submits a POST request to the URL as specified by its parent `<h:form>`, which defaults indeed to the current request URL (you know, "postback"). The `action` attribute basically invokes a bean method and uses the returned value as navigation case outcome. An URL does not necessarily represent a sensible navigation case outcome.

Just use `window.open()` instead on a simple `<p:button>`.

```
<p:button value="show document" 
    onclick="window.open('#{verDocumentoController.url()}');return false;" />
```

You can also do this on a `<p:commandButton>`, but that's unnecessarily overcomplicated.