# Primefaces open page in new tab on button click

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have this

```
<h:outputLink value="http://.....index.html"
target="_blank">open</h:outputLink>
```

but it shows like link. How can I create this like button? I need button "open". When I press to this button I need open my link in new tab of browser.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30630941/1599699

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please mention your PF version we also used like below and it worked in older version Try it let us know

```
<p:button  value="Open" href="http://.....index.html" target="_blank" />
```